# Want to target array element in an array

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce

I want to target the array element which is in the timeslot array. This is the code.

```
function example_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
    $active = array(10 => t('10 - 11 am'), 11 => t('11 - 12 pm'), 12 => t('12 - 1 pm'), 13 => t('1 - 2 pm'), 14 => t('2 - 3 pm'),15 => t('3 - 4 pm'), 16 => t('4 - 5 pm'), 17 => t('5 - 6 pm'), 18 => t('6 - 7 pm'), 19 => t('7 - 8 pm'), 20 => t('8 - 9 pm'), 21 => t('9 - 10 pm'));

    $default_date=date("y-m-d"); $current_time = date('H');
    if($current_time <= 19) {
        $myvalues = example_pane_value($default_date);
        $default_time = $myvalues[0]; $time_slot_title=$myvalues[1]; $current_orders = $myvalues[2];
        //print "time".$default_time." date".$time_slot_title;
        $form['time_slot'] = array(
            '#type' => 'radios',
            '#title' => $time_slot_title,
            '#default_value' => $default_time,
            '#options' => $active,
        );

        if (variable_get('blocker_enable_1', 0)) {
            $form['time_slot'][$active][11] = array( '#disabled' => TRUE,);
        }
    } 
}
```

How will i target the active array's item which is named 11 and make it disable as it is a radio button in a radio group. Can someone kindly explain it.

Comment: your are missing closing tags `}` ...

Comment: actually its a big function and i have put only a part of it which im working on. Am I targeting it properly ?

Comment: You can't disable an array element. There is no such thing as that. You only can delete it if you want it out of the array with e.g. `unset($form['time_slot'][$active][11])`.

Comment: pls specify with test cases

Answer (score 0):

For drupal I think the only way to disable it - is using JavaScript and perform check in form_validate.

U'll need to do something like this in form:

```
drupal_add_js(
    "$(#RadiosId input[value='ValueToDisable']).prop('disabled', true);",
    "inline"
);
```

And in form validate:

```
example_pane_checkout_form_validate($form, &$form_sublit){
    if ($form_state['values']['time_slot'] == $ValueToDisable ){
        form_set_error('time_slot', t('NO HACKING PLS!');
    }
}
```